# UPDATE or DELETE first then INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, sql-delete

I'm asking this again, because I can't get a straight answer from other questions on SO.

My situation is as follows, two tables, `phones` and `features`.

Structure:

**phones**

- id
- brand_id
- model
- picture
- published

**features**

- id
- phone_id
- feature

Now, `features` contains a whole lot of values, which only between 1 & 4 will correspond to a certain phone via `phone_id`.

Now, when I *update* features, do you think **deleting** and then **inserting** new features again or **updating** existing features will be best?

// edit:

**specials**

- id*
- phone_id
- contract_id
- start_publish
- finish_publish
- published

**contract**

- id*
- name
- benefit
- duration
- price, etc.

**brand**

- id
- name
- logo

So basically, a special links a phone and a contract together, and grabs info from both tables for output. Then during that process, each phone's features get loaded separately using a function.

// edit 2:

Oh, and only **one** phone's features will be deleted/updated at a time, and also, only between 1-4 features will be deleted at a time. Also, features can always be more or less, and never a set number.

Comment: updating is a better option, as a single query is required.

Comment: Depends on situation and the schema of your database. Can you desc your tables?

Comment: @Andy I'll put some info in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of features per phone will ever change, then you must delete and insert. To update, you'd need to:

- get the current set of features
- figure out what is different, what was added, and what was removed
- run queries to update, insert new data, and delete old data.

Where as if you just delete the whole list and re-insert them, you save yourself some maintenance headaches.

If consistency of your data is an issue or concern (the data is deleted but an error happens before insert causing the script to not complete) then wrap your queries in a transaction.

Take this example:

I have a blog with `Posts(id, title, body)` and `Categories(id, post_id, category)`. My first Post, "Hello World" is categorized under "meta, php, and javascript". Then a year later, I revise the post to have some information about mysql (or I add a mysql category) and take out javascript.

Here's what I'd need to do (mostly psuedocode):

```
//old set
SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE post_id=1

foreach($categories as $category) {
    if(in_array($category['id'], $_POST['categories']) {
        //this category is in the new set and the old set, do nothing
    }
    elseif(!in_array($category['id'], $_POST['categories']) {
        //this category is in the old set, but not the new one, delete it
        $queries[] = "DELETE FROM Categories WHERE id=".$category['id'];
    }
    else {
        //new category, add it
        $queries[] = "INSERT INTO Categories()..."
    }
}

foreach($queries as $item) {
    //run query
}
```

Versus this:

```
DELETE FROM Categories WHERE post_id=$_POST['id']

foreach($_POST['categories'] as $item) {
    INSERT INTO Categories() ...
}
```

Personally, I think option #2 is better.

Comment: @AnriëtteCombrink exactly, and less headaches too.

Answer (score 2):

When you "update features" you do just that, `update`.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I'm leaning to the other side seeing that keeping track of feature id's is much more of an effort than just deleting where phone_id is correct and then just inserting from scratch.

Comment: @AnriëtteCombrink please elaborate on this comment. what do you mean "keeping track of feature ids is much more of an effort?" this doesn't make sense. if you are editing a feature, you should already have the feature id.

Comment: I never outputted the features' id's in my initial update form.

Comment: @AnriëtteCombrink `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id ?>" />`

Comment: @AnriëtteCombrink Are your `ids` going to stay the same? Deleting and reinserting seems like it would cause a major issue with broken URL's

Comment: @dqhendricks Yes, thank you, I know that, I just didn't put that in.

Comment: @Paul No URL's are derived from these features, they are just outputted as static information.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE should be used. Alternatively, deleting and inserting can be done in one REPLACE command.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Also, if features can be shared (many to many relationship), you may want to consider a third table that only links phone ids to feature ids.